How to scrape HTML with Python?
I'm working on a Python script to scrape data from this page: https://www.immobiliare.it/search-list/?criterio=rilevanza&__lang=it&idContratto=1&idCategoria=1&raggio=300&centro=45.185878%2C9.156321&pag=1#1466423673
I've written this script, but the HTML I get is "different" from what I see in the browser, making it impossible for me to parse the data on the site. How can I solve this?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

url = 'https://www.immobiliare.it/search-list/?idContratto=1&idCategoria=1&criterio=prezzo&ordine=asc&__lang=it&raggio=300&centro=45.185878%2C9.156321&pag=1'

content = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, "lxml")

print(soup.prettify())

title_element = soup.find("div", class_="in-realEstateListHeader__title")
print(title_element)


Have you considered to execute the JavaScript code coming with the received page in order to generate the content?

How can i do it?

See my answer for what you are maybe missing to understand. Not always is there a content there and it seems that in case of the URL you mention there is no HTML content you expect to get.

Here is one tested way to get that information (which is hydrated in page via XHR calls from an API endpoint, viewable in Dev tools -- Network tab, which we will scrape):
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import json
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

big_df = pd.DataFrame()
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

for x in range(1, 4):
    url = f'https://www.immobiliare.it/api-next/search-list/real-estates/?raggio=300&centro=45.185878%2C9.156321&idContratto=1&idCategoria=1&criterio=prezzo&ordine=asc&__lang=it&pag={x}&paramsCount=99&path=%2Fsearch-list%2F'
    r = s.get(url)
    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['results'])
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], ignore_index=True)
print(f'there are {big_df.shape[0]} records')
display(big_df.head())

Result in terminal:
there are 55 records
idGeoHash   realEstate.dataType realEstate.id   realEstate.uuid realEstate.advertiser.agency.id realEstate.advertiser.agency.type   realEstate.advertiser.agency.showOnlyAgentPhone realEstate.advertiser.agency.phones realEstate.advertiser.agency.bookableVisit.isVisitBookable  realEstate.advertiser.agency.bookableVisit.virtualVisitEnabled  realEstate.advertiser.agency.isPaid realEstate.advertiser.agency.label  realEstate.advertiser.agency.displayName    realEstate.advertiser.agency.guaranteed realEstate.advertiser.agency.showAgentPhone realEstate.advertiser.agency.showLogo   realEstate.advertiser.agency.imageUrls.small    realEstate.advertiser.agency.imageUrls.large    realEstate.advertiser.agency.agencyUrl  realEstate.advertiser.supervisor.type   realEstate.advertiser.supervisor.imageGender    realEstate.advertiser.supervisor.phones realEstate.advertiser.supervisor.imageType  realEstate.advertiser.supervisor.displayName    realEstate.advertiser.supervisor.label  realEstate.advertiser.hasCallNumbers    realEstate.contract realEstate.isNew    realEstate.luxury   realEstate.price.visible    realEstate.price.value  realEstate.price.formattedValue realEstate.price.priceRange realEstate.properties   realEstate.title    realEstate.type realEstate.typology.id  realEstate.typology.name    realEstate.visibility   realEstate.hasMainProperty  realEstate.isProjectLike    seo.anchor  seo.title   seo.metaTitle   seo.url realEstate.advertiser.supervisor.imageUrl   realEstate.advertiser.agency.customType
0   u0n9036g    list-real-estate    110235237   44e6ad9e-3829-53a0-be2a-8cde26bc98e0    227312.0    agency  False   [{'type': 'vTel1', 'value': '0382 183 0297'}]   True    False   True    agenzia FONDOCASA PAVIA 2   False   False   True    https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1031007980.jpg  https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1031007982.jpg  https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/227312/fondocasa-pavia-via-xx-settembre/ agent   male    [{'type': 'vTel1', 'value': '0382 183 0297'}]   agent   Simone Imbroisi agente immobiliare  True    sale    False   False   True    125000.0    € 125.000   100.001 - 150.000 &euro;    [{'income': False, 'multimedia': {'photos': [{'id': 1494710293, 'caption': '', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1494710293/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192563, 'caption': 'soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192563/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192591, 'caption': 'soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192591/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192611, 'caption': 'soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192611/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192623, 'caption': 'soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192623/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192635, 'caption': 'soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192635/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192649, 'caption': 'cucina', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192649/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192669, 'caption': 'cucina', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192669/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192681, 'caption': 'soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192681/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192691, 'caption': 'soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192691/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192707, 'caption': 'disimpegno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192707/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192723, 'caption': 'stabile', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192723/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192739, 'caption': 'disimpegno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192739/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192757, 'caption': 'bagno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192757/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192771, 'caption': 'stabile', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192771/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192791, 'caption': 'stabile', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192791/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192805, 'caption': 'stabile', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192805/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192825, 'caption': 'stabile', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192825/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192839, 'caption': 'stabile', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192839/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192867, 'caption': 'stabile', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192867/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490192549, 'caption': 'stabile', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490192549/xxs-c.jpg'}}], 'virtualTours': [], 'hasMultimedia': True}, 'bathrooms': '1', 'ga4Bathrooms': '1', 'bedRoomsNumber': '1', 'floor': {'abbreviation': '2', 'value': '2°, con ascensore', 'ga4FloorValue': '2'}, 'floors': '2 piani', 'ga4Condition': 'Buono / Abitabile', 'condition': 'Buono / Abitabile', 'price': {'visible': True, 'value': 125000, 'formattedValue': '€ 125.000', 'priceRange': '100.001 - 150.000 &euro;'}, 'rooms': '1', 'elevator': True, 'surface': '35 m²', 'surfaceValue': '35 m²', 'typology': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Appartamento'}, 'typologyV2': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Appartamento'}, 'typologyGA4Translation': 'Appartamento', 'ga4features': ['cancello elettrico', 'fibra ottica', 'videocitofono', 'porta blindata', 'esposizione interna', 'accesso per disabili', 'impianto tv centralizzato', 'arredato'], 'caption': 'Appartamento in vendita a Pavia, Centro Storico', 'category': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Residenziale'}, 'description': 'CORSO GARIBALDI - Proponiamo in vendita in ottimo contesto tranquillo e riservato a pochi passi da tutte le attrattive culturali e turistiche della città, grazioso e moderno monolocale pronto da abitare posto all'ultimo piano di uno stabile signorile. L'immobile ci accoglie su un ingresso che conduce alla zona giorno e notte, molto ariosa e luminosa e dotata di cucina a vista; un disimpegno fruibile con armadiatura ed un bagno finestrato con box doccia completano la soluzione. Gli affacci trovano sfogo nella zona interna dello stabile garantendo massima riservatezza e tranquillità. Riscaldamento autonomo, basse spese condominiali, disposizione degli spazi e posizione strategica garantiscono un ottimo acquisto sia in ottica di investimento, sia come acquisto personale.', 'energy': {'zeroEnergyBuilding': False, 'thermalInsulation': None, 'emission': None, 'heatingType': 'autonomo, ad aria, alimentato a metano', 'airConditioning': 'autonomo, freddo/caldo', 'GA4Heating': 'Autonomo'}, 'photo': {'id': 1494710293, 'caption': '', 'urls': {'thumb': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1494710293/thumb.jpg', 'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1494710293/xxs-c.jpg', 'medium': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1494710293/m-c.jpg', 'large': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1494710293/xxl.jpg'}}, 'location': {'latitude': 45.1833, 'longitude': 9.1555, 'marker': 'marker', 'region': 'Lombardia', 'province': 'Pavia', 'macrozone': 'Centro', 'microzone': 'Centro Storico', 'city': 'Pavia', 'nation': {'id': 'IT', 'name': 'Italia', 'keyurl': 'Italia'}}, 'furniture': 'Arredato', 'featureList': [{'type': 'rooms', 'label': '1 locale', 'compactLabel': '1'}, {'type': 'surface', 'label': '35 m²'}, {'type': 'bathrooms', 'label': '1 bagno', 'compactLabel': '1'}, {'type': 'floor', 'label': 'Piano 2', 'compactLabel': '2'}, {'type': 'elevator', 'label': 'Ascensore', 'compactLabel': 'Sì'}, {'type': 'furniture', 'label': 'Arredato'}]}] Monolocale via Siro Comi 6, Centro Storico, Pavia   ad  14  Appartamento    premium False   False   Monolocale via Siro Comi 6, Centro Storico, Pavia   Monolocale via Siro Comi 6, Centro Storico, Pavia   Vendita Appartamento Pavia. Monolocale in via Siro Comi 6. Buono stato, secondo piano, riscaldamento autonomo, rif. 110235237   https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/110235237/   NaN NaN
1   u0n9037e    list-real-estate    110240695   221cea99-1163-5d50-9806-0fa871f864af    131165.0    agency  False   [{'type': 'vTel1', 'value': '0382 153 1425'}]   True    False   True    agenzia M Erre Immobiliare  False   False   True    https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/425843957.jpg   https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/425843959.jpg   https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/131165/m-erre-pavia/ agent   male    [{'type': 'vTel1', 'value': '0382 153 1425'}]   agent   Michele Resegotti   agente immobiliare  True    sale    False   False   True    145000.0    € 145.000   100.001 - 150.000 &euro;    [{'income': False, 'multimedia': {'photos': [{'id': 1490342087, 'caption': 'Vista palazzina', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490342087/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490342257, 'caption': 'Vista Piazzetta', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490342257/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490343239, 'caption': 'Disimpegno ingresso', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490343239/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490343689, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490343689/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490343987, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490343987/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490344267, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490344267/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490344455, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490344455/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490347121, 'caption': 'Vista camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490347121/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490347211, 'caption': 'Vista camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490347211/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490348237, 'caption': 'Vista camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490348237/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490349509, 'caption': 'Vista camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490349509/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490349851, 'caption': 'Vista cucina', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490349851/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490351213, 'caption': 'Vista palazzina', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490351213/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490351389, 'caption': 'Vista Piazzetta', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490351389/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490352591, 'caption': 'Disimpegno ingresso', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490352591/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490352901, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490352901/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490353135, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490353135/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490353351, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490353351/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490353681, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490353681/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490353973, 'caption': 'Vista soggiorno/camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490353973/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490355329, 'caption': 'Vista camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490355329/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490355621, 'caption': 'Vista camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490355621/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490355863, 'caption': 'Vista camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490355863/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490356183, 'caption': 'Vista camera letto', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490356183/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1490356515, 'caption': 'Vista cucina', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490356515/xxs-c.jpg'}}], 'virtualTours': [], 'hasMultimedia': True}, 'bathrooms': '1', 'ga4Bathrooms': '1', 'bedRoomsNumber': '1', 'floor': {'abbreviation': None, 'value': '2 piani: Seminterrato, 1°', 'ga4FloorValue': 'seminterrato, 1'}, 'floors': '3 piani', 'ga4Condition': 'Buono / Abitabile', 'condition': 'Buono / Abitabile', 'price': {'visible': True, 'value': 145000, 'formattedValue': '€ 145.000', 'priceRange': '100.001 - 150.000 &euro;'}, 'rooms': '2', 'elevator': False, 'surface': '62 m²', 'surfaceValue': '62 m²', 'typology': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Appartamento'}, 'typologyV2': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Appartamento'}, 'typologyGA4Translation': 'Appartamento', 'ga4features': ['cancello elettrico', 'porta blindata', 'impianto tv centralizzato', 'arredato', 'cantina', 'esposizione doppia'], 'caption': 'Pavia nel cuore del centro storico...', 'category': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Residenziale'}, 'description': 'a pochi metri da Corso Garibaldi e da Piazza della Vittoria, proponiamo appartamento bilocale al piano primo di stabile in buone condizioni manutentive generali. Attualmente l'abitazione risulta locata (a due studenti universitari) con canone mensile pari a 550 Euro (escluso spese condominiali), con Contratto di Locazione in scadenza il prossimo Settembre 2024. L'immobile è composto da un ingresso nel disimpegno, una zona soggiorno (momentaneamente adibito a camera da letto), una camera da letto matrimoniale, un bagno con finestra e una cucina abitabile. Il riscaldamento dell'abitazione è termo autonomo e le spese condominiali sono contenute. Per ulteriori informazioni rivolgersi in sede.', 'energy': {'zeroEnergyBuilding': False, 'thermalInsulation': None, 'emission': None, 'heatingType': 'autonomo', 'GA4Heating': 'Autonomo'}, 'photo': {'id': 1490342087, 'caption': 'Vista palazzina', 'urls': {'thumb': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490342087/thumb.jpg', 'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490342087/xxs-c.jpg', 'medium': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490342087/m-c.jpg', 'large': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1490342087/xxl.jpg'}}, 'location': {'latitude': 45.1833, 'longitude': 9.1567, 'marker': 'marker', 'region': 'Lombardia', 'province': 'Pavia', 'macrozone': 'Centro', 'microzone': 'Centro Storico', 'city': 'Pavia', 'nation': {'id': 'IT', 'name': 'Italia', 'keyurl': 'Italia'}}, 'furniture': 'Arredato', 'basement': 'Cantina', 'featureList': [{'type': 'rooms', 'label': '2 locali', 'compactLabel': '2'}, {'type': 'surface', 'label': '62 m²'}, {'type': 'bathrooms', 'label': '1 bagno', 'compactLabel': '1'}, {'type': 'elevator', 'label': 'No Ascensore', 'compactLabel': 'No'}, {'type': 'furniture', 'label': 'Arredato'}, {'type': 'basement', 'label': 'Cantina'}]}] Bilocale piazzetta Suor Michelina Sannazzaro, Centro Storico, Pavia ad  14  Appartamento    premium False   False   Bilocale piazzetta Suor Michelina Sannazzaro, Centro Storico, Pavia Bilocale piazzetta Suor Michelina Sannazzaro, Centro Storico, Pavia Vendita Appartamento Pavia. Bilocale in piazzetta Suor Michelina Sannazzaro. Buono stato, primo piano, riscaldamento autonomo, rif. 110240695   https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/110240695/   https://pic.im-cdn.it/agenti/212782/985538702/80.jpg    NaN
2   u0n903kk    list-real-estate    110493585   3e8fb0a5-8108-541f-9b4c-6613097c8bb1    245497.0    agency  False   [{'type': 'vTel1', 'value': '0382 153 1597'}]   True    True    True    agenzia AN Immobiliare  False   False   True    https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/954556942.jpg   https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/954556944.jpg   https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/245497/an-immobiliare-pavia/ agent   male    [{'type': 'vTel1', 'value': '0382 153 1597'}]   agent   Maurizio Mannarino  agente immobiliare  True    sale    False   False   True    155000.0    € 155.000   150.001 - 200.000 &euro;    [{'income': False, 'multimedia': {'photos': [{'id': 1495563257, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495563257/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495563173, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495563173/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495563201, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495563201/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495563231, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495563231/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561275, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561275/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561287, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561287/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561303, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561303/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561327, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561327/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561345, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561345/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561377, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561377/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561409, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561409/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561439, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561439/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561475, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561475/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561507, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561507/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561535, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561535/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561559, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561559/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561577, 'caption': '11', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561577/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561597, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561597/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561615, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561615/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561627, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561627/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561645, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561645/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561655, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561655/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561667, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561667/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561675, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561675/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561189, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561189/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561213, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561213/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561247, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561247/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1495561161, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495561161/xxs-c.jpg'}}], 'virtualTours': [], 'hasMultimedia': True}, 'bathrooms': '1', 'ga4Bathrooms': '1', 'bedRoomsNumber': '1', 'floor': {'abbreviation': '1', 'value': '1°', 'ga4FloorValue': '1'}, 'floors': '2 piani', 'ga4Condition': 'Ottimo / Ristrutturato', 'condition': 'Ottimo / Ristrutturato', 'price': {'visible': True, 'value': 155000, 'formattedValue': '€ 155.000', 'priceRange': '150.001 - 200.000 &euro;'}, 'rooms': '2', 'elevator': False, 'surface': '45 m²', 'surfaceValue': '45 m²', 'typology': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Appartamento'}, 'typologyV2': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Appartamento'}, 'typologyGA4Translation': 'Appartamento', 'ga4features': ['cancello elettrico', 'porta blindata', 'impianto tv centralizzato', 'arredato', 'cantina', 'esposizione doppia'], 'caption': 'Bellissimo Appartamento nel Cuore del Centro Storico', 'category': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Residenziale'}, 'description': 'Vieni a scoprire questa meraviglia nel cuore pulsante di Pavia! Situato in uno degli storici edifici del XII/XIII secolo, la rinomata "Casa Beccaria", questo appartamento è stato completamente ristrutturato e arredato con gusto, offrendoti un'esperienza di vita unica nel suo genere. Caratteristiche dell'immobile: Ubicazione privilegiata nel centro storico di Pavia, con tutti i servizi essenziali a portata di mano. Termo autonomo. Spese condominiali contenute. Accogliente, con ambienti ben distribuiti per soddisfare ogni tua esigenza abitativa. Completamente arredato con mobili qualità, pronto per essere abitato fin da subito. Questo appartamento rappresenta un'opportunità unica nel suo genere per chi cerca un connubio tra storia, comfort e praticità nel cuore della città. Non lasciarti ', 'energy': {'zeroEnergyBuilding': False, 'thermalInsulation': None, 'emission': None, 'heatingType': 'autonomo, a radiatori, alimentato a gas', 'GA4Heating': 'Autonomo'}, 'photo': {'id': 1495563257, 'caption': '1', 'urls': {'thumb': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495563257/thumb.jpg', 'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495563257/xxs-c.jpg', 'medium': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495563257/m-c.jpg', 'large': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1495563257/xxl.jpg'}}, 'location': {'latitude': 45.1834, 'longitude': 9.1575, 'marker': 'marker', 'region': 'Lombardia', 'province': 'Pavia', 'macrozone': 'Centro', 'microzone': 'Centro Storico', 'city': 'Pavia', 'nation': {'id': 'IT', 'name': 'Italia', 'keyurl': 'Italia'}}, 'furniture': 'Arredato', 'basement': 'Cantina', 'featureList': [{'type': 'rooms', 'label': '2 locali', 'compactLabel': '2'}, {'type': 'surface', 'label': '45 m²'}, {'type': 'bathrooms', 'label': '1 bagno', 'compactLabel': '1'}, {'type': 'floor', 'label': 'Piano 1', 'compactLabel': '1'}, {'type': 'elevator', 'label': 'No Ascensore', 'compactLabel': 'No'}, {'type': 'furniture', 'label': 'Arredato'}, {'type': 'basement', 'label': 'Cantina'}]}]    Bilocale via Antonio Mantovani 4, Centro Storico, Pavia ad  14  Appartamento    top False   False   Bilocale via Antonio Mantovani 4, Centro Storico, Pavia Bilocale via Antonio Mantovani 4, Centro Storico, Pavia Vendita Appartamento Pavia. Bilocale in via Antonio Mantovani 4. Ottimo stato, primo piano, riscaldamento autonomo, rif. 110493585  https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/110493585/   https://pic.im-cdn.it/agenti/466088/1488058119/80.jpg   NaN
3   u0n9036y    list-real-estate    107999891   f9cac0c0-d927-58b0-a8d1-52e0af80948d    237028.0    agency  False   [{'type': 'vTel1', 'value': '0382 162 0081'}]   True    True    True    agenzia Tempocasa Pavia - Giardino  False   False   True    https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1115580848.jpg  https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1115580850.jpg  https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/237028/tempocasa-pavia/  agent   male    [{'type': 'vTel1', 'value': '0382 162 0081'}]   agent   Tempocasa Pavia agente immobiliare  True    sale    False   False   True    155000.0    € 155.000   150.001 - 200.000 &euro;    [{'income': False, 'multimedia': {'photos': [{'id': 1446736461, 'caption': '1 Esterno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736461/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736463, 'caption': '2 Esterno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736463/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736467, 'caption': '3 Soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736467/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736469, 'caption': '4 Soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736469/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736471, 'caption': '5 Soggiorno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736471/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736473, 'caption': '6 Cucina', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736473/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736475, 'caption': '7 Cucina', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736475/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736477, 'caption': '8 Camera 1', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736477/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736479, 'caption': '9 Camera 2', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736479/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736481, 'caption': '10 Bagno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736481/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736483, 'caption': '11 Vista', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736483/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736485, 'caption': '12 Esterno', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736485/xxs-c.jpg'}}, {'id': 1446736487, 'caption': 'Immobile certificato', 'urls': {'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736487/xxs-c.jpg'}}], 'virtualTours': [None], 'hasMultimedia': True}, 'bathrooms': '1', 'ga4Bathrooms': '1', 'bedRoomsNumber': '2', 'floor': {'abbreviation': '2', 'value': '2°', 'ga4FloorValue': '2'}, 'floors': '3 piani', 'ga4Condition': 'Da ristrutturare', 'condition': 'Da ristrutturare', 'price': {'visible': True, 'value': 155000, 'formattedValue': '€ 155.000', 'priceRange': '150.001 - 200.000 &euro;'}, 'rooms': '3', 'elevator': False, 'surface': '77 m²', 'surfaceValue': '77 m²', 'typology': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Appartamento'}, 'typologyV2': {'id': 14, 'name': 'Appartamento'}, 'typologyGA4Translation': 'Appartamento', 'ga4features': ['impianto tv centralizzato', 'cantina'], 'caption': 'Pavia / Centro Storico', 'category': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Residenziale'}, 'description': 'L'immobile in vendita si trova nel centro storico di Pavia, al secondo ed ultimo piano di un edificio storico. Si tratta di un appartamento composto da tre locali. L'appartamento si presenta in buone condizioni. Gli ambienti sono luminosi e ben distribuiti, con una metratura complessiva di circa 75 metri quadrati. L'ingresso dell'immobile si apre su un ampio soggiorno, che funge da zona giorno, inoltre, è presente un comodo ripostiglio, utile per riporre oggetti e accessori. Adiacente al soggiorno si trova la cucina abitabile, dotata di tutti i comfort necessari. La zona notte è composta da due camere da letto, entrambe di dimensioni generose. Una delle camere dispone di un parapetto, da cui si può godere di una piacevole vista sul centro storico di Pavia. Completa l'appartamento un bagno ', 'energy': {'zeroEnergyBuilding': False, 'thermalInsulation': None, 'emission': None, 'heatingType': 'autonomo, a radiatori, alimentato a metano', 'GA4Heating': 'Autonomo'}, 'photo': {'id': 1446736461, 'caption': '1 Esterno', 'urls': {'thumb': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736461/thumb.jpg', 'small': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736461/xxs-c.jpg', 'medium': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736461/m-c.jpg', 'large': 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1446736461/xxl.jpg'}}, 'location': {'latitude': 45.1837, 'longitude': 9.1556, 'marker': 'marker', 'region': 'Lombardia', 'province': 'Pavia', 'macrozone': 'Centro', 'microzone': 'Centro Storico', 'city': 'Pavia', 'nation': {'id': 'IT', 'name': 'Italia', 'keyurl': 'Italia'}}, 'basement': 'Cantina', 'featureList': [{'type': 'rooms', 'label': '3 locali', 'compactLabel': '3'}, {'type': 'surface', 'label': '77 m²'}, {'type': 'bathrooms', 'label': '1 bagno', 'compactLabel': '1'}, {'type': 'floor', 'label': 'Piano 2', 'compactLabel': '2'}, {'type': 'elevator', 'label': 'No Ascensore', 'compactLabel': 'No'}, {'type': 'basement', 'label': 'Cantina'}]}] Trilocale via Siro Comi, Centro Storico, Pavia  ad  14  Appartamento    premium False   False   Trilocale via Siro Comi, Centro Storico, Pavia  Trilocale via Siro Comi, Centro Storico, Pavia  Vendita Appartamento Pavia. Trilocale in via Siro Comi. Da ristrutturare, secondo piano, riscaldamento autonomo, rif. 107999891 https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/107999891/   https://pic.im-cdn.it/agenti/263868/985148216/80.jpg    tempocasa
4   u0n903f8    list-real-estate    109439083   5d4b575f-9edd-5de6-91f3-5b506321e43c    57962.0 agency  False


display() ???

Yes, if you're in a Jupiter notebook. Otherwise you can use print() @Claudio

@Claudio display in Jupyter makes the dataframe show in a better format than print. However, it’s not needed if df.head() is the last line of the cell; Jupyter automatically displays the dataframe in that case.
